# Pre defined conversion source report Adwords API AWQL

Tags: php, google-ads-api, awql

I have a basic access manager account and a production Adwords Account, I understand AWQL its a query language but what I dont get is where in the docs I get the exact filed names and FROM REPORT name ???

I have setup a report on my adwords account to track Conversion Sources which has these fields

- Conversion source
- Conversions
- Cost / conv.
- Conv. rate
- View-through conv.

I am trying to access these fields through Adwords API using AWQL

what are the equivalent AWQL filed names and FROM REPORT names ?

Where to look for the field names in google adwords api docs ?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of googling I found the fields on adwords all reports documentation

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/all-reports